# Papervision 3D: How can I force dimensions on a collada file

Tags: actionscript, scale, papervision3d, dimensions, collada

I'm working with Collada files and I need them to be a certain size.  When instantiating them in pv3d you set the filename, materials, and scale.  Scale works like a percentage, and there's no way to get the width, height, or depth of the DAE once in flash.  I want to be able to specify the size of DAE in 3D space relative to other pv3d native geometry.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to calculate that using the [Axis Aligned Bounding Box](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounding_volume) (AABB).

In the complete handler, access the **aabb** of the object containing geometry.
Based on how nested your DAE objects are, you might need to go down the hierarchy 
a bit to get to the objects that actually contain geometry, as the **.geometry**
property, which holds **aabb** is null for empty container.

e.g.

```
//in the complete handler, assuming object is a reference to a DisplayObject3D of the collada
//containing geometry
trace('width: ' + (object.geometry.aabb.maxX - object.geometry.aabb.minX)); 
            trace('height: ' + (object.geometry.aabb.maxY - object.geometry.aabb.minY)); 
            trace('depth: ' + (object.geometry.aabb.maxZ - object.geometry.aabb.minZ));
```

HTH,
George